How and where to download headless chrome (offline) latest for RHEL7.9
I am trying web scrapping using the pyppeteer module. I am using the executablePath for headless chrome. Few sites failing to open the page due to older version of chrome.
My team used the HeadlessChrome/119.0.6045.105. So I am trying to use the latest version but no idea what's the latest version Headless chrome. Can someone shed the light to download (offline) headless chrome?

you can download it from here
https://googlechromelabs.github.io/chrome-for-testing/
or here https://sites.google.com/chromium.org/driver/downloads?authuser=0

Please share the code that's failing and the stack trace as a [mcve].
